# How do I share a Google Sheet with 'read only' permissions?

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, google-drive-sharing

Given some [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/) I'm aware of the `Share` button in the top right corner. However, the default settings allow anyone with the [share url](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en) to edit the sheet.

Is it possible to set permissions so the file is `read-only`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you pull up the share menu - click the little drop down an choose "view"

[image]

ALso if you want to disable copying and downloading, click on "advanced" on the bottom right and check the 2 boxes at the bottom

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add the users to the list through google REST API's ?

Comment: Is there a way to share the link with read only access? I want to make a sheet publicly available, but with read only access for anyone but me.

Comment: @kiml42 yes the permission is called view only

Answer (score 0):

You can set the permissions for link access in a similar way to the previous answer.
From the sharing popup - click `advanced`. This adds a row for public access, set to `off` by default. You can click it to access the `Link Sharing` popup in which you can set it to be publicly accessible to those with the link. Once you've turned link sharing on a drop-down appears to select what public users can do - either view only, view and comment or full edit access.