# How do I transfer a copy of Google Sheets to someone?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to give someone a Google Sheets that I made so they can use it independently of my sheet. I don't want to ever be able to read/write/update their sheet. I'm aware there are various options for adjusting [permissions on Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/103851/148978).

For example, if I email someone a text file and they edit it, I don't know what they've done to their copy and they don't know what I've done to mine.

How do I do this with a Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give them a modified shareable link to a copy of your file.

First, make a copy of your sheet: `File -> Make a copy...`

Second, create a shareable link with `can view` permissions:

[image]

Note the end of the url:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wyqMk01sd-erhS3XthafqFtRSTO2nC6xS6Kp7au0sK0/edit?usp=sharing
```

Finally, send them the URL of your sheet with `/copy` appended on the end - it directly refers them to this page, by which then can then duplicate it and have their own copy:

[image]

Note the end of the url:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wyqMk01sd-erhS3XthafqFtRSTO2nC6xS6Kp7au0sK0/copy
```

Comment: I think you may need to send a link that was generated with `edit` permissions and then modify the end matter with `/copy`. For example, I generated a shareable link with edit permissions: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zI4ouvg4GLTK47t813gZk3B1tGvDXyaCtFoljv7giAY/edit?usp=sharing` and then I modified that url like how you suggested: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zI4ouvg4GLTK47t813gZk3B1tGvDXyaCtFoljv7giAY/copy` but I don't think any url will work. Do you agree?

Comment: actually, now that I think about it's that's probably a bad idea because then they could just slightly modify the url back to edit and they would be able to edit it!

Comment: yeah unless you keep a static copy that only is for sharing/copying I suppose :-/ but I think your right about the part about needing it to have edit permissions - makes sense

Comment: Hmmm, so it sounds like that's the only way so far: make a static copy, edit the permissions, modify the url? Seems like a lot just to share a file ;)

Comment: I do one of two things when sharing, if its a template where each use generally needs to be its own copy - then i give the person that url with /copy, otherwise I share it (within the org or outside if needed) via the sharing permissions

Comment: Just discovered something! Your `/copy` trick still works if you make the share link have `view only` permissions, so you don't have to worry about them modifying the link you give them after the fact. I think the flow is: work on `SpreadsheetA`, make a `Copy of SpreadsheetA`, generate a sharelink with view only permissions, edit the url with `/copy`, profit!

Comment: sweet - win for the team :-D

Comment: Ya, I think you should be careful about the permissions, it would be a bummer if someone went back after the fact and edited a template you had just right, accidently or otherwise. Copy with read-only permissions ftw!

Comment: want me to append a note onto my answer - or would you rather?

Comment: I'll take care of it, images are a pain

Comment: thx ;) adding more characters to post my comment

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER October 2020

After further research the procedure has been abbreviated and can be achieved as follows without the need to create a shareable link as per the following instructions:

[image]